# Passing an empty JSON array as a parameter to an @JsonProperty annotated method

Tags: json, jackson, rest-assured

I'm trying to pass the an empty array value in my payload for a Rest Assured test so that it contains:

```
{
  "areaCode": []
}
```

I have a POJO representing the data object:

```
@Data
public class AreaDetails {

//declare fields here
@JsonProperty("areaCode")
private JsonArray areaCode;

}
```

Then trying to set the value in my test:

```
@Test
public void updateAreaCodes()  {

    a = new AreaCodes();

    //set other fields
    a.setDealerOptions(<PARAM>);
```

I'm unclear what to pass as the parameter here, or indeed if I should declare the field as a JsonArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**POJO :**

```
@Data
public static class Example {

    @JsonProperty("areaCode")
    private List<Object> areaCode = null;

}
```

**Test :**

```
    Example e = new Example();
    e.setAreaCode(new JSONArray());

    String abc = new ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(e);
    System.out.println(abc);
```

Comment: thanks again for your help. I only appear to have Gson's JsonArray in my class path which won't work. I keep getting a com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException  Maybe I'm getting confused between Gson and Jackson

Comment: I've used [json-simple](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1)

Comment: ah, thank you.   Yes that works but produces an empty array with whitespace in the centre.  The request fails so I wonder if this is the issue or a red herring

Comment: I tried few other ways as well but I end up with the same result.
When I try to get the size of the array it returns 0 which is as expected so that's convincing

Comment: ok thanks, this is a PATCH request and the others were POSTS - I think something else is wrong

Comment: @Steerpike Hi, do u have any idea how to configure the objectmapper to get rid of the whitespace when the array is empty